# Variable field in "Save Responses to a file" in jMeter -

Tags: jmeter

I've been beating myself up with jMeter to learn a few new things.  I am using 2.13.  One thing I played with yesterday is the "Save Responses to a file" listener.  I've put the path of the filename I want to create in the "Filename prefix" field and it seems to work well.

Using the "Variable Name" field is more troublesome.

[image]

The Apache documentation says that the field is:

> Name of a variable in which to save the generated file name (so it can
>   be used later in the test plan)

Great!  I gave the variable a name and tried to access the value in a BeanShell PostProcessor script.

```
String startCode = vars.get("START_CODE");
String filename = vars.get("FILENAME");
String transNum = vars.get("TRANSACTION_NUM");
System.out.println("startCode=" + startCode + ", transNum=" + transNum + ", filename=" + filename);
```

I always get null.  I've hacked at this a lot of my day yesterday.  I've tried pre-declaring the variable in a "User Defined Variables".  That will at least give me an empty string or whatever value I put in the Value column of the UDF.

Gotta say I'm green on the BeanShell too, except my access to the other variables fetch the correct values, so it's a little confusing.

Comment: I've had trouble getting `System.out.println` working. Have you tried `log.info`? It will appear in the log opened in the top right corner.

Comment: No, System.out.println() works for me (output goes to the console window where jmeter.bat is started from).  Anyway, I tried your suggestion and the log.info() gives me the same result - null.

Comment: Thing will become easy for you if you know the order of things it execute. like pre-processor ,post-processor , listener etc. search for these things it will definitely help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So what is the problem? I doubt you cannot use variable name with [Save responses to a file](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Save_Responses_to_a_file) listener, it hasn't changed for ages and used to work quite well. If you need any extra documentation on using the listener you can check out [Performance testing: Upload and Download Scenarios with Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-performance-test-upload-and-download-scenarios-apache-jmeter) article.

If you have problem accessing that `FILENAME` variable value generated in Listener in PostProcessor - this is kind of expected as Listeners occur **AFTER** PostProcessors as certain PostProcessors (especially Beanshell and similar) can modify the result. So in order to be able to access FILENAME variable from Beanshell:

1. Use [Beanshell Listener](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Listener) instead of Beanshell PostProcessor
2. Make sure Beanshell Listener is **below** Save Responses to a file listener, otherwise you'll run into the same situation

Comment: OK, using a Beanshell Listener instead of a Beanshell PostProcessor allowed me to retrieve the FILENAME variable from the "Save Responses to a file"

Comment: This is not working for sake of god! I am getting value always null..why this should be too difficult ??